# Summation of Binomial Expansion with multiplicative factors

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Consider the following summation:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}(1-p)^{n-k}p^k$$

If the $k$ term was not present it would be a simple binomial. However, because of the $k$ term I am unable to derive the sum.

I believe the summation should be equal to $np$ (The summation is part of a larger expression, which upon solving using a different approach gives the $np$ result). I have tested this for smaller values of $n = \{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for $k\geq 1$, $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ and therefore the sum can be evaluated as a *simple binomial*:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}(1-p)^{n-k}p^k
&=np\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1}(1-p)^{n-1-(k-1)}p^{k-1}\\
&=np((1-p)+p)^{n-1}=np.
\end{align}$$
Along the same lines we show the more general identity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k(k-1)\cdots (k-j)\binom{n}{k}(1-p)^{n-k}p^k
=n(n-1)\cdots (n-j)p^{j+1}.$$

Comment: @Samik It is a *simple binomial*!

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is the mean of a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$.  This is well known to be $np$.